# Caching images fetched from the internet?

Tags: android

I want to cache the images i fetch over the internet. 
So that each time the images are swiped in the gallery, they wont be fetched each time. If some one could tell me how i could do that with this code it would be greatly appreciated.

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}


 my.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(n);

    }
});
gameNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}); 

//Executing AsyncTask in background thread to get images.
MyTask myTask = new MyTask();

myTask.execute();

}
```

Get Image Methods:

```
//Method to get images from text documents that will by updated every month.

public void getImages() throws IOException{


    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImages.txt");
    HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

            InputStream is = buf.getContent();


            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");

              imageUrl = total.toString();
              Log.v("getImage1", "Retreived image");
            }
     }



            public void getImage2() throws IOException{

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImage2.txt");
                HttpResponse response;


                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


                        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

                        BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

                        InputStream is = buf.getContent();


                        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                            total.append(line + "\n");

                          imageUrl2 = total.toString();
                          Log.v("getImage2", "Retreived image");
                        }
                }



                        public void getImage3() throws IOException{

                            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webimage3.txt");
                            HttpResponse response;


                                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


                                    HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

                                    BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

                                    InputStream is = buf.getContent();


                                     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                                    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                                    String line;
                                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                                        total.append(line + "\n");

                                      imageUrl3 = total.toString();
                                      Log.v("getImage3", "Retreived image");
                                    }

                        }

                        public void getImage4() throws IOException{

                            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImage4.txt");
                            HttpResponse response;


                                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


                                    HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

                                    BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

                                    InputStream is = buf.getContent();


                                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                                    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                                    String line;
                                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                                        total.append(line + "\n");

                                      imageUrl4 = total.toString();


                            }
}
```

ImageAdapter class:

```
                    //ImageAdapter that gets the URL of the images and put them in a format to be set to gallery
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            /** The parent context */
            private Context myContext;public ImageAdapter() {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }
            /** URL-Strings to some remote images. */

            public String[] myRemoteImages = {imageUrl,imageUrl2,imageUrl3,imageUrl4};






            /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
            public ImageAdapter(Context c) { this.myContext = c; }





            /** Returns the amount of images we have defined. */
            public int getCount() { return this.myRemoteImages.length; }

            /* Use the array-Positions as unique IDs */
            public Object getItem(int position) { return position; }
            public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

            /** Returns a new ImageView to
            * be displayed, depending on
            * the position passed. */
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

            try {

                            URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
                            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();

                            conn.connect();

                            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();  
                            /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                            /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */

                            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                            bis.close();
                            is.close();
                            Log.v(imageUrl, "Retrieving image");

                            /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
                            i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                            Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);
                    }

            /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            return i;
            }

            /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views
            * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */
            public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
            /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
            return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
            }
            } 





        //the important AsyncTask method. running the background thread to get the images and set them to the gallery.
            private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {try {
                        getImages();
                        Log.v("MyTask", "Image 1 retreived");
                        getImage2();
                        Log.v("MyTask", "Image 2 retreived");
                        getImage3();
                        Log.v("MyTask", "Image 3 retreived");
                        getImage4();
                        Log.v("MyTask", "Image 4 retreived");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("MainMenu retreive image", "Image Retreival failed");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                return null;
            }
            @Override

            protected void onPostExecute(Void notUsed){
                ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
                      .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainMenu.this));


            }

       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this, assuming the filename from the url is unique, You could write them to the sd card or internal storage. For example:

```
File cacheDir = new File("my-cache-dir");
File[] fileList = cacheDir.listFiles();
int index = linearSearch.(fileList, uri.getFileName());

if(index != -1){
 // load from file
} else {
 // load from web
}
```

There are several other ways to do this, such as with a database or flat file. Just remember that you have to generate the same cache key every time for what's cached.

Comment: Is there a tutorial any where for this?

Comment: @YogoTi the tutorial for writing to the sd card is [available](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). As for generating the key that is specific to your implementation. What your writing is a specialized [Web Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache) so if you're worried about your keys just use the url.

Comment: Hey dan i know i may be asking for alot but im not really a hug fan of the android developer guide. Are you familiar with doing this?

Comment: @YogoTi which specific part did you want an example for?

Comment: Just from my code. I retrieve the images in my ImageAdapter in the code. So i just need a example of how i cache when the images are fetched there, and how to load the cache the next time the images are needed(I want to cache them because the images will change every month)